# Enable Access Control in MongoDB doesn't work

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication, mongodb-query

Everything worked fine when I used as a connection string: `mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/data`. After add Enable Access Control with connection string: `mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/?authSource=data` stops working.

I'm connected to mongodb but in application I see on request `This request has no response data available`. But for connection string to `mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/data` there was data.

To add authentication I used this instruction  [Enable Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/):

I created admin:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser(
...   {
...     user: 'admin',
...     pwd: 'password',
...     roles: [ { role: 'root', db: 'admin' } ]
...   }
... );
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
> exit;
```

I changed mongo config file - mongod.cfg:

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

I logged in as admin:

```
> use admin
> db.auth('admin','password');
1
```

I created new user:

```
use data
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "user",
    pwd: "pwd",
    roles: [
       { role: "dbAdmin", db: "data" },
    ]
  }
)
db.grantRolesToUser(
   "user",
   [ "readWrite" , { role: "read", db: "data" } ],
   { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 4000 }
)
```

And I used: `mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/?authSource=data` as a connection string, but there is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The reason was `authSource` in connection string. Before:

```
 "connectionString": "mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/?authSource=data"
```

After:

```
 "connectionString": "mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/data"
```

Now it's working fine.

Comment: No,  authSource is fine, what it probably means is that you created the user under `admin`

Comment: But now it's working fine. I tried also created user with `role: "dbAdmin"` and finally it is not `root` but `dbAdmin` as user.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you need to get what's wrong or will repeat the error. Try with this and you get what I say: `mongodb://user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/data?authSource=admin` The question is correct anyways (+1).

Comment: After used your connection string I get error [Function: Error] { stackTraceLimit: 16, prepareStackTrace: undefined } Invalid connection string

Comment: @Minsky I use it on another pc and I do not create admin there, just user `role: "dbAdmin"` using this connection string `user:pwd@0.0.0.0:27017/data` and works fine. So maybe creating an admin is unnecessary to this?

Comment: Maybe check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470 And host should be rather `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or the real hostname rather than `0.0.0.0`